# Which kind of plaster to use on concrete walls, prior to painting?

Tags: preparation

I have a small holiday apartment in Europe that has pre-fabricated concrete walls. The surfaces are relatively smooth but I want to prepare them for painting by applying a skim coat of plaster. Which kind of plaster is the most appropriate for this purpose.

By the way, these are internal walls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any top coat plaster should be OK.

It might be worth priming the surface with a diluted PVA solution (5 parts water to 1 part PVA - from memory so double check) to seal it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to just seal the wall, prime it, and then paint (maybe using a thick nap roller) avoiding have to put down any plaster?  After you have sealed and primed the wall, a coat (or two) of paint with a thick nap roller might be able to smooth out any small defects in the pre-fabricated wall.  And painting is going to be much easier than putting plaster down.  (Of course patch any major defects in the wall prior to sealing it.)

Comment: I agree, priming (maybe putting down UGL drylok to help with any possible moisture issues) would be a much better idea than plastering.